# How to compare two date values using SQL

Tags: sql

How to compare two dates the first column table one 2013-04-04 05:47:52.000 the second one from other table 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000.
I want to compare just yy/month/day; if they are equal, I get second id table.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 9):

For Sql Server you can do this:

```
CAST(table1date AS DATE) = CAST(table2date AS DATE)
```

Example of how it could be used:

```
declare @dateTime1 as datetime = '2013-04-04 05:47:52.000'
declare @dateTime2 as datetime = '2013-04-04 00:00:00.000'

if CAST(@dateTime1 AS DATE) = CAST(@dateTime2 AS DATE)
    print 'yy mm dd is the same'
else
    print 'not the same'
```

Or using tables:

```
declare @dateTime1 as datetime = '2013-04-04 05:47:52.000'
declare @dateTime2 as datetime = '2011-04-04 00:00:00.000'

declare @table1 table (id1 int, dt1 datetime)
declare @table2 table (id2 int, dt2 datetime, table1id int)
insert into @table1 values (1, @dateTime1)
insert into @table2 values (2, @dateTime2, 1)

select case when CAST(@dateTime1 AS DATE) = CAST(@dateTime2 AS DATE) then t2.id2 else t2.table1id end as id
from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2 on t1.id1 = t2.table1id
```

Comment: i use this database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743900/fact-table-ssis-sqlserver-r2008

Comment: i tried this code  but i get error:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "dbo.FACT_TABLE.DATE_DEBUT_ALRM" could not be bound.

Merge fact_table as target using( select top 1 idDateDeb,PK_Date,
Week_Of_Year
from dbo.dim_date_Debut)as source 
on cast(source.PK_Date as date)=cast(dbo.FACT_TABLE.DATE_DEBUT_ALRM as date)
when matched then
 update set target.ID_TEMP_DEB=source.idDateDeb;

Comment: @user2586714, I'm not sure how you are using the code, but I've added a working example. See if that helps

Comment: i want to do triggers when data adding on fact_table id_date_deb and id_date_fin inserted by comparing date  from fact_table and calendar and get Id and numberOfWeek

Comment: @user2586714, does the second example using tables help?

Comment: @user2586714, well, this question only asks to compare 2 dates from 2 different tables and getting the id from one of the table depending on the date comparison. I believe my second example does exactly this and answers this question. You are now asking me to answer a different post which is not relevant to this question. I'll have a closer look at your other post, but as far as I can tell, this has been answered.

Answer (score 5):

```
IF CAST(DateField1 AS DATE) = CAST(DateField2 AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 4):

By compare you mean to find the difference?

How about

`DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp